# How to set value in 2 way binding in angular with a function

Tags: angular, data-binding

I have a problem that how can I set a value in 2 way binding with a function.

the code looks like that:

```
 <app-charge-station-modification-sort-order
              [(canAddMore)]="setCanAddMoreSortOrder(eForm.controls.sO.value)"
              [index]="index"
              [formGroup]="form"
              [selectedValues]="sOValues"
              controlName="sO"
            ></app-charge-station-modification-sort-order>
```

and ts file:

```
public  setCanAddMoreSO(sO: number):boolean{
    return isNaN(sortOrder) ? false : true;
  }
```

but I got this error:

Unhandled Promise rejection: Errors during JIT compilation of template for xxx
Error: Unexpected token '='

any solutions??

Answer (score 0):

you can not 2 way bind to a function. How should it assign a value to a function call?
you have to use a property in the two-way-binding
https://angular.io/guide/two-way-binding

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure of your intentions but you could try writing it as below.

I am assuming that in your 'app-charge-station-modification-sort-order' component that you have declared @Input and @Output variables and that you are emitting the @Output variable.

```
<app-charge-station-modification-sort-order
   [canAddMore]="setCanAddMoreSortOrder(eForm.controls.sO.value)"
   (canAddMoreChange)="setCanAddMoreSortOrder($event)">
</app-charge-station-modification-sort-order>
```

In your component...

```
  @Input() canAddMore!: boolean;
  @Output() canAddMoreChange = new EventEmitter<number>();
```

"Sugared" two way binding [()] does rely on @Input and @Output variables following the convention propertyName for @Input and propertyNameChange for @Output for Angular to automatically match them together.

Can't help but think though that there must be a better way for you to achieve what you are trying to achieve though but this might help? I'm making a lot of assumptions here.